# Swap values in a array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, swap

I have an array like this:

```
item[0][0] = 1;
item[0][1] = 20;

item[1][0] = 3;
item[1][1] = 40;

item[2][0] = 9;
item[2][1] = 21;


(...)
```

I want to swap these "values" like:

```
int[] aux = item[0];

item[0] = item[1];
item[1] = aux;
```

But this isn't working since i think that's passes references and not the values.

Comment: @Kon, I'm working with a multimensional-array...

Comment: What error are you seeing? Getting an unexpected result in the code down the line?

Comment: This should work. May be something else is not working? Post output you are getting or any errors.

Comment: @idknow Could you please post what do you expect to be swapped? See my posted answer, as the code is working correct. Except I misunderstood your intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related with the use of references.

Must be used `System.arraycopy(array, 0, otherArray, 0, array.length);` as the copy method.

Comment: Could you please post a little bit more code which explains how this solution could solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working correct. see the small snippet below

```
int[][] item = {{1, 20}, {3, 40}, {9, 21}};
for (int[] ints : item) {
    System.out.printf("%s ", Arrays.toString(ints));
}
System.out.println("");

// to swap the array item[0] and array item[1]
int[] aux = item[0];
item[0] = item[1];
item[1] = aux;
for (int[] ints : item) {
    System.out.printf("%s ", Arrays.toString(ints));
}
System.out.println("");
```

**output**

```
[1, 20] [3, 40] [9, 21] 
[3, 40] [1, 20] [9, 21]
```

or to swap the values within an array (instead of swapping two arrays)

```
// to swap the values of array item[0]
// in the verbose way
int[] aux = item[0];
int temp = aux[0];
aux[0] = aux[1];
aux[1] = temp;
item[0] = aux;    
for (int[] ints : item) {
    System.out.printf("%s ", Arrays.toString(ints));
}
System.out.println("");
```

**output**

```
[1, 20] [3, 40] [9, 21] 
[20, 1] [3, 40] [9, 21]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public static void swapArrays(int a[], int b[]) {
    if (a.length != b.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arrays must be of same size");
    }

    int temp[] = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, a, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, b, 0, a.length);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int b[] = {3, 4, 5};
    swapArrays(a, b);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
}
```

If they are of a different size, you'll need to allocate a new array or copy only a certain range.